# Filter Magento collection but not products, using distinct

Tags: php, sql, collections, magento, filter

In my magento store I am trying to retrieve a list of youtube videos from a DB table, some videos are duplicated.

I'm looking to filter videos by using distinct video "value" but can't seam to find any information about using distinct with addFieldToFilter()

```
// get video collection

$collection = Mage::getModel('video/video')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('provider', 'youtube');

// filter by video value

$collection->addFieldToFilter('value')->distinct(true);
```

By removing `$collection->addFieldToFilter('value')->distinct(true);` it works, but retrieves all the videos.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$collection->getSelect()->distinct(true);
```

But this will retrieve distinct values based on id.
If you want to retrieve videos using distinct video values, you should group by "value".

```
$collection->getSelect()->group('value');
```

If you want to debug the query executed :

```
$collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Fabrizio... you make me smile. You make it look so easy, that works perfectly and even i can understand what you have explained. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While adding the join make sure blank array is passed in the third parameter.

```
$this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    'sales_order_item',
    'sales_order_item.order_id = main_table.order_id',
    []
);
```

After that add the following to apply DISTINCT

```
$this->getSelect()->distinct(true);
```