# how to get date from database and display without any repetition?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.4

I had a function which is pulling all the dates from database against each record.

```
public function getAllYears() {

    $collection = Mage::getModel('press/press')->getCollection()->getYears();

    return $collection;

}
```

and am displaying it as :

```
<?php  

        $coll =  $this->getAllYears();

    ?>


         <?php foreach ($coll as $list): ?>

                <?php echo $list["year"]; ?>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
```

It is giving me all the years(dates), without caring for repetition, whereas I want is same date must not be repeated.

Mean same year must not repeat.
Any help?

Comment: You can't add groupby clause in query?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511314/filter-magento-collection-but-not-products-using-distinct I don't know much about Magento but what you are looking for would imply a need for a query using DISTINCT

Comment: Try this with your query


->setOrder('year', 'ASC')->group('year');

Comment: @Shashank it probably doesn't even need the order since `group` automatically sorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps change the display code to:

```
<?php
$years = array();
$coll =  $this->getAllYears();
foreach ($coll as $list)
    $years[] = $list['year'];
$years = array_unique($years);
?>

<?php foreach ($years as $year): ?>
<?php echo $year; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<?php  
$coll =  $this->getAllYears();

$lastyear
foreach ($coll as $list)
{
    if($list["year"] != $lastyear) {
    echo $list["year"];
}
$lastyear = $list["year"]
}
?>
```

Comment: That's assuming that the years returned are ordered which isn't necessarily the case