# How to get product collection with multiple category?

Tags: magento, collections

In my custom module i am getting category ids.
sometime its single category and sometime multiple category

my code is:

```
$exist_prdcat_id="4,5"; //multiple category
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $collection->joinField(
            'category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 
            'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left'
        )
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
                array('finset' => array($exist_prdcat_id)),
        ));
```

Now using this code i am not getting product so how can i get product when its single or multiple category ids

Answer (score 3):

Try below -

```
$exist_prdcat_id=array(4,5); //multiple category
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $collection->joinField(
            'category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 
            'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left'
        )
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
                array('finset' => $exist_prdcat_id),
        ));
```

Put your category id's in array.

reference : [Filter product collection on two categories Magento 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120381/filter-product-collection-on-two-categories-magento-1-7)